# Implementing Forgot password in Spring giving garbage URL

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. I want to implement the forgot password functionality. For that, I am using the secret question method. I have created a JSP page, where I recieve the values like username, secretanswer and then I check if the values exist and then save the new password which the user has given. I am having a problem wiht the JSP page, when I click submit, it shows me some garbage URL. I believe it is some tiny mistake, I am unable to see. Kindly let me know what is going wrong.

Apache tomcat error URL :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /id=0,%20username=null,%20password=null
```

Controller function for changing password :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/forgotpassword")
    public String forgotPassword(Model model){
       model.addAttribute("person",new Person());
       return "forgotpassword";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/changepassword")
    public String changepassword(@ModelAttribute("person") Person f,Model model){
        System.out.println("Did we reach here on submit");
        personService.checkAuthenticitiy(f.getUsername(), f.getSecretanswer(), f.getNewpassword());
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        return "redirect:/forgotpassword";
    }
```

JSP page :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forgot Passsword page</title>
</head>
<body>

<td><a href="<c:url value='/' />" >Go Home</a></td>

<h1>
    Change password
</h1>

<c:url var="addAction" value="/changepassword" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${person}" commandName="person">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="username">
                    <spring:message text="username"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="username"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="secretquestion" >
                    <spring:message text="secretquestion"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="secretquestion"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="secretanswer" >
                    <spring:message text="secretanswer"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="secretanswer"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="newpassword" >
                <spring:message text="newpassword"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="newpassword"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Person model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

 @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;


    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "secretquestion")
    private String secretquestion;

    @Column(name = "secretanswer")
    private String secretanswer;

    @Transient
    private String newpassword;
     //Getters and setters for all.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/changepassword" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${person}" commandName="person">
```

should be

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/changepassword" ></c:url>
 <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
```

person is not your action

Comment: Thank you Pravin, I will try that tomorrow as I am not in office anymore. Are you sure that is the only mistake?

Comment: Ya everything else looks perfect to me. There isn't any requestMapping for ${person} so it cause such error

Comment: No need of thanks, you can share that other problem too

Comment: The other problem was I was using Bcrypt to create encrypted secret answers, turns out, bcrypt always create different encrypted text...facepalm... its solved, changed algo.. :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975366/image-upload-using-hibernate-inside-postgresql Hi pravin, can you check out this question.