# Image upload using Hibernate inside PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am working on a Spring-MVC application and I must use image upload for storing images in Database. I tried to go through examples on internet, but my overall observation is there is some argument regarding type of upload, and who manages it. Nevertheless, I am uploading the image from an HTML, saving it in Database as OID, using byte array with @Lob to save. I am unable to see the image preview when i use :

I will post code of how I have achieved it, kindly let me know whats wrong.

HTML code for image preview :

```
 <img src="${product.productimage}" width="100" height="100"/>
```

When I use product.getImage().toString in service, I get weird characters by 'B[jlkisf12', but only 12-13 of them, I imagine that is the path.

Entity :

```
@Column(name = "productimage")
byte[] productimage;  // With getters and setters
```

JSP file :

```
   <c:url var="add" value="/product/add"></c:url>
<form:form action="${add}" commandName="product">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty product.productname}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="productid">
                        <spring:message text="productid"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="productid" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="productid" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productname">
                    <spring:message text="productname:"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productname"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productdescription">
                    <spring:message text="productdescription"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productdescription"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productcondition">
                    <spring:message text="productcondition"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productcondition"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productage">
                    <spring:message text="productage"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productage" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productean">
                    <spring:message text="productean"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productean" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productisbn">
                    <spring:message text="productisbn"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productisbn" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="ordernumber">
                    <spring:message text="ordernumber"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="ordernumber" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productimage">
                    <spring:message text="productimage"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input type="file" path="productimage" />
            </td>
        </tr>



    </table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <c:if test="${!empty product.productname}">
                <input type="submit"
                       value="<spring:message text="Edit Product"/>" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${empty product.productname}">
                <input type="submit"
                       value="<spring:message text="Add Product"/>" />
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form:form>

<br>
<h3>Product List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listProducts}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Product ID</th>
            <th width="80">Product image</th>
            <th width="120">Product name</th>
            <th width="120">Product description</th>
            <th width="120">Product condition</th>
            <th width="120">Product age</th>
            <th width="120">Product EAN</th>
            <th width="120">Product ISBN</th>
            <th width="120">Product ordernumber</th>
            <th width="120">Product owners id</th>

            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="product">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.productid}</td>
                <td>${product.productimage} </td>
                <td>${product.productname}</td>
                <td>${product.productdescription}</td>
                <td>${product.productcondition}</td>
                <td>${product.productage}</td>
                <td>${product.productean}</td>
                <td>${product.productisbn}</td>
                <td>${product.ordernumber}</td>
                <td>${product.user1id}</td>
          <img src="${image}" width="100" height="100"/> //image not found
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Edit Product</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removeproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Delete Product</a></td>
            </tr>
            <img src="${product.saveimage}" height="100" width="100">
        </c:forEach>


    </table>
</c:if>
```

Controller :

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/product/show",method= RequestMethod.GET)
     public String listProducts(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,Model model)   {
     User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
     model.addAttribute("product", new ProductBasic());
     model.addAttribute("listProducts",this.productBasicService.listProduct(user));
     BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     stringBuilder.append("data:image/png;base64,");
     stringBuilder.append(base64Encoder.encode(productBasic.getProductimage())); 
     String image = stringBuilder.toString();
     model.addAttribute("saveimage",image);
     return "product";
 }

@RequestMapping(value="/product/add")
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,Model model){
    User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
    model.addAttribute("product", new ProductBasic());
    productBasicService.addProduct(user,productBasic);
    return "redirect:/product/show";
}
  @RequestMapping("/removeproduct/{id}")
    public String removeProduct(@PathVariable("id") int productid,Model model) {
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("listProducts",this.productBasicService.listProduct(user));
        this.productBasicService.removeProduct(productid,user);
        return "redirect:/product/show";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editproduct/{id}")
    public String updateProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,@PathVariable("id") Integer id,Model model){
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("product", this.productBasicService.getProductById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listProducts",this.productBasicService.listProduct(user));
        return "product";
    }
```

NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
    sun.misc.CharacterEncoder.encode(CharacterEncoder.java:188)
    com.WirTauschen.UserController.listProducts(UserController.java:67)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

What am I doing wrong? Kindly let me know.

Comment: p.getImage().toString returns Image is[B@54b65954

Comment: Well, what's actually *in the DB*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Controller or method add below code for image

```
    BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    StringBuilder imageString = new StringBuilder();
    imageString.append("data:image/png;base64,");
    imageString.append(base64Encoder.encode(bytes)); //bytes will be image byte[] come from DB 
    String image = imageString.toString();
    modelView.put("imagetoDisplay",image);// put in your model object for using in your JSP
```

And in your JSP

```
  <img src="${imagetoDisplay}" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was in meeting.Hello Pravin, I am adding only 1 image right now for testing, later I have to add multiple images. I can use something which is more dynamic. Plus, when I try to use <img src> tag  anywhere in the product.jsp file, it cannot find the contents within the $ bracket.

Comment: Above code will works fine with dynamic behavior.. If you fetching image directly from DB it will returns you byte[] you need to encode that byte[] using base64 ...
have you tried above ?? and ${} should work .. can you share error or something

Comment: The ${} does not work,it says not found image. Can you please check the post I have edited.

Comment: you have done coding for image in `@RequestMapping(value="/product/add")` this URL is might call after you submit the page/form .. According to me you should write that code in `@RequestMapping(value="/product/show",method= RequestMethod.GET)` or the method from whom above jsp is returned

Comment: You are correct, I just changed it to /product/show. KIndly check the updated post. I am getting NullPointerException because of that. Error code is in post.

Comment: String image = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Encoder.encode(productBasic.getProductimage());  This line throws nullPointerException when it accesses getter in entity i.e getProductImage();

Comment: productBasic is null there so productBasic.getProductimage() give you NPE. you need to get byte[] of image there it would be there where all your product information resides

Comment: Product information resides in entity...and thats a getter of entity. I have time, as I am out of office...if you can think of something...please let me know.

Comment: Any ideas? In PGAdmin3, it shows it has Binary data. Thats all.

Comment: Hi Pravin, Thanks, Can you check my post now, in Controller as you can see I am adding it to model.addAttribute("saveimage",image);. But as there can be multiple products, i decided to use StringList, it shows me a nullpointererror. But your solution was right on track. If you can just see this problem. Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You can add in list of string and use that list in your jsp

Comment: I am getting nullPointerExceptionn for  stringList.add(image);. I am initializing the list like this:  List<String> stringList = null;. If i don't instantiate the list, it says It cannot compile as list is not initialized.

Comment: You should use like  `List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: OMG. That was so noob of me. Thanks. It works like a charm now.

Comment: Hi man, Can you check this question about forgot password : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036597/spring-mvc-reset-password-by-sending-email